# php-mysql - need to match two keywords which are supplementary to each other rather than independent ones

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table cav in mysql.

I need to fetch result using php on the basis of two keywords which would search in two columns viz. 'caseno' and 'year'.

In the user form I provide two input fields namely 'keyword' and 'keyword1'.

Wish to show result only when keyword and keyword1 matched exactly with the values already exist in the column 'caseno' and 'year' (in a single row) in the database .

for example if user put 684 as keyword and 2007 as keyword1 query should fetch data of a row where value of caseno column is 684 and value of year column is 2007.

My problem is that suppose I am putting 684 as keyword and nothing in keyword1 even then it is showing the row containing 684, if I put 684 as keyword and 2010 as keyword1 even then it is showing row containing 684.

Wish to show the data of a row where 'caseno' is 684 (user defined keyword) and 'year' is 2007 (user defined keyword.

Have tried the following code:-

```
<?php

   $db_host="";
   $db_user="";
   $db_pass="";
   $db_name="";

   $db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

   if($db->connect_error){
       die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
   }

   ?>
   <?php

   if(!empty($_POST))
   {
   $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword']);
   $bKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword1']);
   $query ="SELECT * FROM cav WHERE caseno like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%' AND 
   year like '%".$bkeyword[0]."%'";

   $result = $db->query($query);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $row_count=0;

   echo '<br><br><br><br><br>
   <center><table class="table-1 mt-2 table-responsive table border="1" 
   table-bordered"><TABLE BORDER=2 BORDERCOLOR=BLACK font size="2">
   <tr>
   <th>S.No.</th>
   <th>Case Type</th>
   <th>Case No.</th>
   <th>Year</th>
   <th>Petitioner Name</th>
   <th>Respondent Name</th>
   <th>First Coram</th>
   <th>Second Coram</th>
   <th>Third Coram</th>
   <th>Written By</th>


   </tr></center> ';
   While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
   $row_count++;  
   echo "<tr><td> ".$row_count." </td><td>". $row['casetype'] . "</td><td>". 
   $row['caseno'] . "</td><td>". $row['year'] . "</td><td>". 
   $row['petitioner'] . "</td><td>". $row['respondent'] . "</td><td>". 
   $row['firstcoram'] . "</td><td>". $row['secondcoram'] . "</td><td>". 
   $row['thirdcoram'] . "</td><td>". $row['writtenbycoram'] . "</td>  
   </tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
   }
   else {
   echo "<br>Result Found: NONE";
   }
   }

   ?>
   html form is 
   <input type="text" name="keyword" autocomplete "off">
   <input type="text" name="keyword1" autocomplete "off">
   <input type="submit" value="Search"><FORM><INPUT Type="button" 
   VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
```

Wish to show result only when values of both the columns i.e.'caseno' and 'year' match exactly to the keywords given by user. if user put only 684 or only 2007 or 684 and 2010 or 784 and 2007 it will show 'no result found'

Comment: Don't use `%`  , `'%".$bkeyword[0]."%'` means that before and after `$bkeyword[0]` can be any character and any number of characters.So when you pass empty string `""` you are saying `%nothing%` which means it will take every single record from the database.If you want to simpy match records, use equation.

Comment: Your problem was using AND when you could have used OR. Check @JackSiro's answer below

Comment: Thanks Alex, Oyonde and Jack for your valuable response, I fix my code and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code here could solve your issue much easily since I see you were just missing a few points to make it work as you wanted. I have also made the rest code much better to manage

```
$html = '';
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $aKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword']);
        $bKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['keyword1']);

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM cav WHERE caseno LIKE "%'.$aKeyword[0].'%" OR caseno LIKE "%'.$bKeyword[0].'%"';
    $result = $db->query($query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row_count=0;

        $html .= '<br><br><br><br><br>';
        $html .= '<center><table class="table-1 mt-2 table-responsive table border="1" 
        table-bordered"><table border="2" bordercolor="black" font-size="2">';
        $html .= '<tr>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Case Type</th>
        <th>Case No.</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Petitioner Name</th>
        <th>Respondent Name</th>
        <th>First Coram</th>
        <th>Second Coram</th>
        <th>Third Coram</th>
        <th>Written By</th>';


        $html .= '</tr></center> ';

        While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
            $row_count++;  
            $html .= '<tr><td> '.$row_count.' </td><td>'. $row['casetype'] . '</td><td>'. 
            $row['caseno'] . '</td><td>'. $row['year'] . '</td><td>'. 
            $row['petitioner'] . '</td><td>'. $row['respondent'] . '</td><td>'. 
            $row['firstcoram'] . '</td><td>'. $row['secondcoram'] . '</td><td>'. 
            $row['thirdcoram'] . '</td><td>'. $row['writtenbycoram'] . '</td>  
            </tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</table>';
    }
    else {
        $html .= '<br>No results found';
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Your problem was using **AND** instead of using **OR**